# Unrecognized option: -cp with ProcessBuilder on Windows only

Tags: java, windows, classpath, processbuilder

So I am working on a cross platform bootstrap program which works correctly on OSX/Linux but returns the following error message in Windows:

> Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
> Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
> Unrecognized option: -cp C:/myapp/realm/bin/Launcher.jar;C:/myapp/_jvm/jre/../lib/tools.jar;C:/myapp/realm/shared/lib/jetty-util-8.1.4.v20120524.jar

If I print out my list of ProcessBuilder Arguments and run those arguments on the command line it will run successfully.  The command should be

> C:/myapp/_jvm/jre\bin\java -javaagent:C:/myapp/realm/bin/spring-agent.jar -cp C:/myapp/realm/bin/Launcher.jar;C:/myapp/_jvm/jre/../lib/tools.jar;C:/myapp/realm/shared/lib/jetty-util-8.1.4.v20120524.jar
> -Xmx256m -Xms200m -Xss128k -XX:+UseBiasedLocking -XX:+UseNUMA -DprocessType=realm -Dcert.framework.license=C:/myapp/realm/license/my.license -Djav
> a.security.policy=C:/myapp/realm/security/java.policy -Djava.security.properties=C:/myapp/realm/security/java.security -Djava.secur
> ity.auth.login.config=C:/myapp/realm/security/jaas.conf -Drealm.home=C:/myapp/realm -Duser.dir=C:/myapp/realm/
> bin -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:/myapp/realm/endorsed;C:/myapp/_jvm/jre/lib/endorsed -Djava.ext.dirs=C:/myapp/realm
> /ext;C:/myapp/_jvm/jre/lib/ext  -Dlog4j.configuration=file:C:/myapp/realm/conf/log4j.properties -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.Log=or
> g.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger com.myapp.launcher.ProviderLauncher

I have tried placing quotes around the classpath, using double slashes et cetera to no avail help would be appreciated.. here is the code:

> ```
>    String mainClass = args[0];
>    String propFile = args[1];
>    FileInputStream fis =new FileInputStream(propFile);
>    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
>    String line = null;
>    ArrayList<String> argList = new ArrayList<String>();
>    while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
>        if(line.startsWith("#"))
>            continue;
>        String trimmedLine = line.trim();
>        if(trimmedLine.isEmpty())
>            continue;
>        Matcher m = p.matcher(trimmedLine);
>        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
>        while(m.find()){
>            String content = m.group(1);
>            String envContent = System.getenv(content);
>            if(envContent == null || envContent.isEmpty())
>                envContent = System.getProperty(content);
>            m.appendReplacement(sb, envContent);
>        }
>        m.appendTail(sb);
>        if(!sb.toString().startsWith("\"-") && !sb.toString().startsWith("-") && argList.size() > 0)
>            argList.set(argList.size()-1, argList.get(argList.size()-1)+File.pathSeparator+sb.toString());
>        else argList.add(sb.toString());
>    }
>
>    ArrayList<String> cmdList = new ArrayList<String>();
>    cmdList.add(System.getenv("JAVA_HOME") + File.separator + "bin" + File.separator + "java");
>    cmdList.addAll(argList);
>    cmdList.add(mainClass);
>    System.out.println(cmdList.toString());
>    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmdList);
>    new ProcessBuilder(line);
>    File f = new File(System.getenv("MY_DIR") + File.separator + "logs" +File.separator + "provider-console.log");
>    if(!f.exists())
>        f.createNewFile();
>    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
>    pb.redirectOutput(f);
>    pb.directory(new File(System.getenv("MY_DIR") + File.separator + "bin"));
>    Process p = pb.start();
> ```

Here is the toStringed cmdList:

> [C:/myapp/_jvm/jre\bin\java, -javaagent:C:/myapp/realm/bin/spring-agent.jar, -Xmx256m, -Xms200m, -Xss128k, -XX:+UseBiasedLocking, -XX:+UseNUMA, -cp C:/myapp/realm/bin/Launcher.jar;C:/myapp/_jvm/jre/../lib/tools.jar;C:/myapp/realm/shared/lib/jetty-util-8.1.4.v20120524.jar, -DprocessType=realm, -Dcert.framework.license=C:/myapp/realm/license/jericho.license, -Djava.security.policy=C:/myapp/realm/security/java.policy, -Djava.security.properties=C:/myapp/realm/security/java.security, -Djava.security.auth.login.config=C:/myapp/realm/security/jaas.conf, -Drealm.home=C:/myapp/realm, -Duser.dir=C:/myapp/realm/bin, -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:/myapp/realm/endorsed;C:/myapp/_jvm/jre/lib/endorsed, -Djava.ext.dirs=C:/myapp/realm/ext;C:/myapp/_jvm/jre/lib/ext, -Dlog4j.configuration=file:C:/myapp/realm/conf/log4j.properties, -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger, com.myapp.launcher.ProviderLauncher]

Comment: Can you share more about the original error message?  When do you see it? Is there an associated stacktrace?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The "-cp" and the actual classpath need to be separate entries in the args list, you currently appear to have them as one entry separated by a space.

Comment: Thanks for the second set of eyes, that resolves the problem.  Do you know why it is different between OS?

Comment: Who would have known! Solved my problem.

Comment: so basically somethind like this in ant ```  <arg value="-cp" />
            <arg value="jar_files/*" />```